# Why wont Backgrounder plugin work in Firefox or Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullscreen

I am using a full screen image with Backgrounder Plugin, It works great in Chrome, but wont show the image in Firefox or Explorer, I am using Jquery 4.4

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
$(function() {
  $("#my_background").backgrounder();
});
});


<div id="my_background"><img src="../images/bk/luft.jpg" alt="Lufthavn"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face the same problem with backgrounder. I think the best plugin for your needs is [fullscreenr](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/fullscreenr).
The use is something like this:

**js**

```
// You need to specify the size of your background image here (could be done automatically by some PHP code)
            var FullscreenrOptions = {  width: 1024, height: 683, bgID: '#bgimg' };
            // This will activate the full screen background!
            jQuery.fn.fullscreenr(FullscreenrOptions);
```

**html**

```
<img id="bgimg" src="img/bg.jpg" />
```